# Jest global setup leads to inconsistent test pass/failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, supertest

I'm trying to test an API with jest. Originally all my tests wherein one file and all tests where passing. I wanted to separate my tests into different files. To do this I'm trying to use a global setup file with `beforeEach` and `afterEach`. The problem is that sometimes I run the tests and they pass and other times they fail (different test pass and different fail each time).

package.json

```
{
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "bail": false,
    "preset": "@shelf/jest-mongodb",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"
    ],
    "globals": {
      "authHeaders": {},
      "authId": null
    }
  },
}
```

jest.setup.js

```
const app = require("./index")
const supertest = require("supertest")
const request = supertest(app)
const db = require("./src/db")
const jwtDecode = require("jwt-decode")
const getAuthToken = require("./src/utils/getAuthToken")

let token
let decodedJwt

const getAuthHeaders = token => ({
  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
})

beforeEach(async done => {
  //setup globals available in all tests

  token = await getAuthToken()
  token = JSON.parse(token)["access_token"]
  decodedJwt = jwtDecode(token)
  authId = decodedJwt.sub
  authHeaders = getAuthHeaders(token)

  // Ensure that we have a users collection with our test user
  // who can then call the api
  await request
    .post("/v1/users")
    .set(authHeaders)
    .send({ email: "test@example.com" })
    .expect(200)

  done()
})

afterEach(async done => {
  // Delete the users collection
  await db.instance.dropUsers()
  await db.instance.dropAgencies()

  done()
})
```

users.test.js

```
const app = require("../../../../index")
const supertest = require("supertest")
const request = supertest(app)
const faker = require("faker")

describe("/v1/users/:id", () => {
  test("should return an error when the users do not have a mutual agency", async done => {
      if (!authHeaders || !authId) {
        expect(true).toBe(false)
      }
      let testUserId = null
      let email = faker.internet.email()

      await request
        .post("/v1/users")
        .set(authHeaders)
        .send({ email })
        .expect(200)
        .then(({ body }) => (testUserId = body._id))

      await request
        .get("/v1/users/" + testUserId)
        .set(authHeaders)
        .expect(200)
        .then(({ body }) => {
          expect(body).toHaveProperty("error")
          expect(body.error).toHaveProperty("message")
        })

      done()
    })
})
```

I can run the above once and it will pass and run again moments later and it will fail.

---

Edit:

After further investigation it seems that the issue is something to do with the `afterEach` function not dropping the `Users` collection. When I console log the response of the request made in the `beforeEach` in the `jest.setup.js` file I'm getting an error response saying that the user for the given email already exists.

Comment: When you define a test as `async`, you don't need to call the `done` method. When you see the test fail, what is the error?

Comment: I've updated my question to give more information about what I'm seeing

Comment: Mmmm, is there any other test that populates the database? Maybe you have a test that inserts a record into database after the `afterEach` hook is executed.

Comment: There is other test that populate the database but the thing is when I put a `debbuger` statement in the `beforeEach` and one in the `afterEach` and step through the tests at a slower pace all test pass. I'm wondering if it's some sort of issue with a delay from the db but if I'm await'ing it then then that shouldn't be possible. So I'm stumped

Answer (score 5):

The issue was caused by multiple tests running at the same time, adding the `--runInBand` flag (which forces test to be run serially) fixes the issue.

The error in my thinking was I assumed it was safe to add a user record to the database `beforeEach` and delete it `afterEach` without considering that if two tests run at the same time one would always fail as a user would already exist in the database.

In light of this I think it would be an idea to refactor my setup file so that my test user is only created once for all tests but I need to consider the implications of doing this.

### EDIT:

I have found that I can run test successfully without the `runInBand` flag by switching out my atlas cloud database in favour of `mongodb-memory-server` during tests.